# Does IE 11 support applications developed in Silverlight 5?

Tags: silverlight-5.0, windows-8.1, internet-explorer-11

We have developed a web application with using Silverlight 5. We are facing problems in IE 11. The application is not even loading in IE 11. But it is working fine in IE 10 and other browsers like Chrome and Mozilla.

When we debug, the "**Silverlight.__startup();**" function itself is not called when we focused the silverlight object. Could you please clarify for us whether will IE 11 support Silverlight applications or not. If yes, could you please provide some tips / suggestions to load the SL application in IE 11. If you can able to provide a sample app, that will be great for me.

Also, we are using jquery 1.4.1 version. Will IE 11 support this version or not. If not, which version of jquery we have to use in IE 11?

Comment: Are you using Silverlight.js?

Comment: Yes, i am using the latest one(//v5.1.20125.0)

Answer (score 1):

You should upgrade to the latest version of jQuery.

In principle, Desktop IE11 will support Silverlight in the Trusted Sites and Intranet zones.

1. The Immersive version of IE (Win8/Win8.1 app environment) doesn't support add-ons.
2. Silverlight is a legacy add-on which is not compatible with Enhanced Protected Mode, which is now on-by-default in the Internet Zone.

Answer (score 0):

I just install IE11 replacing IE10 on Windows 7, and all my application Under Silverlight work fine.

What I have done :

- option Internet Intranet : allow initialize activeX
- Parameter compatibility : set to Trust my Intranet Server.

Surprise :  I can look demo of Devexpress.com on Silverlight, without any change on security on Internet

Regards